# Xcode compilation error: audio stream

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I'm facing a problem, my project don't want to compile because of
some framework mismatch.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_audio_stream_open", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_get_duration", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_get_sample_rate", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_close", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_get_channels", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_eos", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
  "_audio_stream_read", referenced from:
      _ears_load_stream in TQEventListener(load.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think its about TQEventListener which need a framework, but I'm not sure...

Comment: add symbolic break point and look where is the error.

Comment: @KAR It's a build error, not a runtime error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Undefined+symbols+for+architecture+arm64